# Codeigniter pagination duplicating results on pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I've some problems, while using pagination.
Here is my code for model:

```
public function count_locations() {
    return $this->db->count_all("locations");
}
public function fetch_locations($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->select('locations.id as location_id, locations.name_ka, locations.description_ka, locations.recomendation, locations.img, locations.nature, locations.culture, locations.resort, regions.region_name_ru, regions.region_type, resort.resort_name_ru, nature.nature_name_ru, nature.nature_name_en, culture.culture_name_ru, culture.culture_lat')
    ->from('locations')
    ->join('regions', 'regions.id = locations.region','left')
    ->join('culture', 'culture.id = locations.culture','left')
    ->join('resort', 'resort.id = locations.resort','left')
    ->join('nature', 'nature.id = locations.nature','left');

    $this->db->order_by('location_id','asc');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
function page(){

    $this->load->view('templates/head');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'location/page';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Location_model->count_locations();
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->Location_model->
    fetch_locations($config["per_page"], $page);

    $this->load->view('location/location',$data);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view("location/pagination", $data);

    $this->load->model('Footer');
    $dataf['links'] = $this->Footer->get_links();
    $this->load->view('templates/footer',$dataf);

    $this->load->view('templates/end');
}
```

And view file content:

```
$object = array();
foreach($results as $data) {
    echo $data['location_id'] . "<br>";
}
echo $links;
```

As a result it gives me 4 elements per page. That's fine. But problem appears when going to next page. Firs page page shows: `56, 57, 58, 59`. Second page: `58, 59, 60, 61`. Third page: `60, 61, 62, 63`.
Results must be: for first page: `56, 57, 58, 59`, 2nd: `60, 61, 62, 63`, 3rd: `64, 65, 66, 67`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that you posted the sequence of items on the pages is not exactly as it is.
I assume u have seen:
   first: 56, 57, 58, 59
   second: 58, 59, 60, 61
   third: 59, 60, 61, 62
but were not very carefully reading it.

Here is why ... You used:

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

checking once what it does https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html tells you that this makes the uri segment be the page number instead of the first item offset on the page as it used to be.

This is just a first guess.
I would suggest learning some basic debugging methodologies.
for example var_dumping some parameters on some key spots would help you find errors much faster instead of waiting for responses on stackoverflow.

hint: find key points in roughly the middle of our code and check wheather or not the proper parameters are passed. And depending of the outcome you go on serching in one or the other half of our code.

here: for example you could var_dump the parameters in the model to know whether its a error in the DB/model or u get the wrong parameters from view/controller.

unless u learn this you will have no fun programming and get stuck in frustrated moments all day long.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$page` is wrong here. You use segment here.

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

This should be as following

```
if ($this->input->get('page')) {
    $sgm = (int) trim($this->input->get('page'));
    $page = $config['per_page'] * ($sgm - 1);
} else {
    $page= 0;
}
```

Now

```
 $data["results"] = $this->Location_model->fetch_locations($config["per_page"], $page);
```